# Stacking to 100% with `seaborn.objects`

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, visualization, seaborn-0.12.x

I'm trying to make a plot with bars or areas rescaled to 100% with the new `seaborn.objects` interface and I can't seem to get `so.Norm()` to work, with or without `by`...

Here's what I've got so far:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so


tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

# bars
(
  so.Plot(tips, x="day", y="total_bill", color="time")
  .add(so.Bar(), so.Agg("sum"), so.Norm(func="sum"), so.Stack())
)

#areas
(
  so.Plot(tips, x="size", y="total_bill", color="time")
  .add(so.Area(), so.Agg("sum"), so.Norm(func="sum"), so.Stack())
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you intend for the height of each (stacked) bar to equal 1, so you'd want to aggregate by `x` values when normalizing:

```
(
  so.Plot(tips, x="day", y="total_bill", color="time")
  .add(so.Bar(), so.Agg("sum"), so.Norm(func="sum", by=["x"]), so.Stack())
)
```

[image]